# How to see array size from a pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following function and like to see array length. The array length pointed should be 91200 and 1459200, but they are printed as `(size of input 8 size of output 8)`. What could be wrong in the following code.

```
int ResizeAreaInference(cudaStream_t stream,  const void* inputs, void* outputs, int upscale, int w, int h, int c)
{    
    //static int cnt=0;
    int n = (int)(w*h);
    const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 128;
    const int NUMBLOCKS = (int)((float)(n+THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1)/THREADS_PER_BLOCK); 
    ResizeAreaKernel<<<NUMBLOCKS, THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 0, stream>>>(static_cast<const float*>(inputs), static_cast<float*>(outputs), upscale, w, h, c, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    //if(cnt==0){
    //  printdatain(static_cast<const float*>(inputs), w*h*c, "inputs.txt", w*c);
    //  printdataout(static_cast<float*>(outputs), w*upscale*h*upscale*c, "outputs.txt", w*upscale*c);
    //}
    //cnt++;
    const float *input = static_cast<const float*>(inputs);
    float *output = static_cast<float*>(outputs);
    std::cout << "size of input " << sizeof(input) << " size of output " << sizeof(output) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting the size in memory of a float pointer. Also, pointers are not arrays. Use standard containers.

Comment: I think you are asking how to debug array out of bounds bug when you do not know the actual size of the array pointed by `inputs` and `outputs`. Is that right?

Comment: @AlexWang Thank you. When I print out array to a file like `myfile << *(ptr+i) << ",";`, I have segmentation fault. What could be reason?

Comment: It might be the actual size of the array pointed by `ptr` is smaller than `i * sizeof(*ptr)`. But without a complete example, who knows..

Comment: If that's a "normal" image-processing interface, I would expect `w*h` (`width*height`) pixels, each of `c` (`colours`) elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you cannot "get array size from a pointer" this way. It is simply not possible.

You will have to calculate the array size another way. For example, you could add another parameter which holds the array size. Or you could use a `std::vector`, which does contain a size.

Comment: Thank you. When I print out array to a file like `myfile << *(ptr+i) << ",";`, I have segmentation fault. What could be reason?

Comment: @batuman I think the segmentation fault error is related to the illegal access of memory probably *(ptr+i) is not a valid memory location that you are trying to de-reference it